# .Net Windows service out of Memory exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

Please let me know how to resolve the following error. Below Out of Memory exception only arises once the code is deployed in Production Machine (i.e once Windows service is up and running on production Machine). It is not replicating in our local.

```
Application: LSRAnalysisService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException
Stack:
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetDaylightTime(Int32, AdjustmentRule)
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetIsDaylightSavingsFromUtc(System.DateTime, Int32, System.TimeSpan, AdjustmentRule, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffsetFromUtc(System.DateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.DateTime.ToLocalTime(Boolean)
   at System.DateTime.FromFileTime(Int64)
   at System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs..ctor(Int32, Int32)
   at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireQueuedTimerCompletion(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

We have a Timer running in windows service.

Please find the code below

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (wcfserviceHost != null)
                wcfserviceHost.Close();
            wcfserviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(AnalysisManager));
            wcfserviceHost.Open();
            Deletefile();
        }

        protected void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Deletefile();
        }

        private void Deletefile()
        {
            try
            {
                timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                timer.Interval = (1000) * 60 * 60;//(10000) * 6;
                timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
                string FilePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FilePath"];
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FilePath);
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectory in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    if (subDirectory.Name == "Temp") continue;
                    if (subDirectory.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                    {
                    subDirectory.Delete(true);
                    }
                }
                timer.Enabled = true;
                timer.Start();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use `System.Threading.Timer`? Also, `System.Timers.Timer` is disposable, you have to dispose it.

Answer (score 2):

Too many timers:

```
   private void addtimer()
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = (1000) * 60 * 60;//(10000) * 6;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Start();

}
protected void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Deletefile();
}
private void Deletefile()
{
    try
    {
        string FilePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FilePath"];
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FilePath);
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectory in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            if (subDirectory.Name != "Temp" && subDirectory.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                subDirectory.Delete(true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```

and in OnStart call addTimer.
Ps: avoid continue whenever it's possible. And most time it is.

Comment: 100% correct. Just to elaborate a little bit: Every time the original timer fired, it would create another timer. The timers that were created would then each create a new timer as well. So on first fire you'd have 2 timers running on 2nd fire 4 on 3rd fire you'd have 8 - basically exponential growth in the number of timers being generated (and trying to fundamentally do the same thing at the same time)

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions given. Will Implement them.